# How do I load specific pictures from iPhone 3G to my PC?

Tags: iphone, photos

I am trying to load pics from my iPhone to my computer, but just want specific pictures.

How can I choose which ones to download.  I already have several downloaded and so when I go to download the additional pictures I took, it wants to download them all again.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different - can you give us some more information about your question? What software are you using to grab the photos off of your phone? And you are running a Windows machine, right?

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be able to right click on the iPhone icon found under my computer, and select explore.  If so, you should be able to select just the ones you want.

I'm not running windows right now so can't check, let me know how it works out.

Comment: Ok tried that, but it didn't work.  I rtl click on iphone icon, but theh only choices were: open, open innew windoe, import pictures.videos, create shortcut, properties.  None of these produced the result I need. Import pics - continues to download all of the pictures.